# osx sys/io.h not found

Tags: macos, header-files

I'd like to compile a c programm developed for linux using cc under os x.
It includes the header sys/io.h.
When compiling I get the error that this file could not be found?
Isn't there any sys/io.h header file under os x?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to compile?

Answer (score 12):

Include `<sys/uio.h>` instead.

or why not both?

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
        #include <sys/uio.h>
#else
        #include <sys/io.h>
#endif
```

In case of Apple OS (OSX/iOS) the code will know compile with `<sys/uio.h>`

Comment: It can't be that straight forward; don't these header files declare different functions etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add it to your project, and it should compile.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/+/master/sysroot/usr/include/sys/io.h

Edit: You need features.h as well

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/+/master/sysroot/usr/include/features.h

Finally got cursor support in my kernel, although the functions in io.h weren't working for me. They compiled fine, and may help someone else. This is the code I'm going forward with...

```
static inline void outb(unsigned short port, unsigned char value)
{
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("outb %1, %0" : : "dN" (port), "a" (value));

}
static inline unsigned char inb(unsigned short port)
{
    unsigned char value;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("inb %1, %0" : "=a"(value) : "Nd"(port));
    return value;
}

void update_cursor(int row, int col)
{
    unsigned short position=(row*80) + col;

    // cursor LOW port to vga INDEX register
    outb(0x3D4, 0x0F);
    outb(0x3D5, (unsigned char)(position&0xFF));
    // cursor HIGH port to vga INDEX register
    outb(0x3D4, 0x0E);
    outb(0x3D5, (unsigned char )((position>>8)&0xFF));
}
```

Comment: So the you add the header file, and... it magically works, yes?

Comment: Yes, the function I was needing is outb() and everything is compiling. Trying to add cursor support to a small kernel... I'll admit I don't have it working yet, but I'm brand new to this.

Answer (score 1):

What bibor has written is perfect. Though my file looks something like this and works well.

```
#ifdef __linux

#include <io.h>

#elseif __apple

#include<uio.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls /usr/include/sys/io.h
ls: /usr/include/sys/io.h: No such file or directory
```

It doesn't look like it.  You may have to do some porting.

Linux has this header file.  It looks like it has to do with [low level port input and output.](http://linux.die.net/man/2/inb_p)

In general, things in /usr/include/sys are going to be operating-system specific, so you'll have to port to a new architecture if it's not already ported.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
The program makes use of functions like outb(), to write values to certain registers. Is there any equivalent header file for os x providing me such functions?

Comment: I found out that if if I want to use low level io under osx I'll have to have kernel mod priv. in other words I'll have to write a kext?

Comment: It would be my guess that you'll have to write a kext, though it depends on the exact device.  OS X provides support for certain devices from userspace.

Comment: well, thanks! I'll do some research about kexts. I heard it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: If it's a simple device, just create a kext with a userclient, and you should be able to build your code to do the same thing as linux through that userclient.