# what is the difference between uio.h and io.h?

Tags: c, linux, posix

Sometimes I see compiler complaining about this line

```
#include <sys/io.h>
```

with

> fatal error: sys/io.h: No such file or directory

If I simply change it to

```
#include <sys/uio.h>
```

It will magically work. Can someone explain to me the difference? Why do some OSes have one but not the other?

Edit: This issue happens on a Linux, not just OS X.

Comment: What is `<sys/io.h>` and why are you including it?

Comment: @melpomene It's a either a header for a posix library or a very widely supported unix one. Not entirely certain which. William, welcome to Mac-land, from the looks of it. They are a bit weird over there. Anyway, this is almost a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762010/osx-sys-io-h-not-found

Comment: @user4581301 Before posting this question, I have already read that one. Unfortunately it didnt help me because I am encountering this issue in fedora, not OS X.

Comment: `<sys/uio.h>` is from POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_uio.h.html

Comment: Doesn't your code even compile when simply commenting out `#include <sys/io.h>`?

Comment: @alk So isnt it better to just use `<sys/uio.h>` for portability? What's the benefit of having `<sys/io.h>`?

Comment: As far as I see this, `<sys/io.h>` is (mostly?) Linux specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is not safe or even sensible to simply change the name of a header file being included when the compiler cannot find that header.  Headers with similar names do not necessarily have anything to do with each other.

That appears to be the case here: the GLIBC header file `sys/io.h` does not declare the vectored I/O functions of the POSIX-specified header `sys/uio.h`, at least not directly.  In fact, GLIBC also provides `sys/uio.h`.  They're different.  Neither C nor POSIX provides any reason to believe that `sys/uio.h` on one system would provide any declarations that are provided by a header named `sys/io.h` on that or any other system.

If you are trying to build C code and some header cannot be found, then the first thing to consider is the include search path, and whether the header name needs a path segments added or removed.  The next thing to consider is whether that header is needed at all in the build environment.  If it is not, then changing the header to name some other header that is actually present will fix the build, but so would deleting the `include` directive altogether.

I'd rate it better, in fact, to remove or comment out such a failing `include` directive, make sure warnings are cranked up, and see what, if any, missing declarations the compiler then complains about.  That will give you a handle with which to determine what header, if any, you should include in place of the missing one.